# Display Messages before results in MS SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am coding several t-sql scripts that can be ran by other persons inside `MS SSMS`.  As such I have used the `PRINT` function to describe the results the script generates.  I would like it if when the script finished executing the focus would be on the `Messages` window and not the results.  Is this possible?

Comment: If they are running queries via SSMS, they should be technical people (developers, DBAs, etc). I'd question why they need such hand-holding if this is the case. If they aren't technical people, giving them SSMS might not be the best choice.

Comment: While I would agree with you in theory, in practice I am not the person who gets to make such decisions.
Also for scripts that do some automated items it can be useful to see the variables the script choose for context before looking at the results.  If nothing else it is annoying to have to switch always from 'Results' to 'Messages' than back to 'Results'

Comment: Spencer Louden, understood. This aspect of IT is the most challenging, even over solving technical problems :)

Comment: Could you use `select` instead of `print` for the messages?

Comment: @sgeddes, using SELECT will send the results to the grid and not to the Messages window at all.

Comment: It appears this isn't possible. Reference [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813788/can-i-get-ssms-to-switch-to-the-messages-tab-programatically).

Comment: @HardCode I would have hopped that in 7 years, SSMS could have improved enough to add a feature to let the user decide if the focus should be on the 'Results' or 'Messages' tab .... oh well

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

according to your request and the following short discussion This chec these option as solution was your needs:

**Option 1:** You asked if you can get the result of query like PRINT which the answer is yes. You have three built-in option to return the result of queries:

1. As Grid (which is what most people use)
2. as file, which mean that the result will be automatically export to a file
3. Return as Text which is exactly the option that fit your request

Check this image and select the option "As Text":
[image]

**Option 2:** You can develop extention to SSMS and change change the tab automatically one the query returns result. For this option Search more information regarding projects type "VSIX" in Dot.Net.

> Note! Developing extension for SSMS require contact the team in order to get special GUIDE for the project.